# How to I configure a link in an email to run a particular stage in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have a pipeline job which uses a Jenkinsfile, to copy a zip file to multiple XLdeploy Enviroments from an Artifactory.
I have segregated the Staging and Production Environments into two stages in Jenkinsfile in the repo.

Now I want to trigger the pipeline job, which will execute the first stage(copy to staging) and then send an email, preferably with a link so that somebody else can approve the execution of the second stage of the Jenkins file(copy to Production). The other user does not always have access to log into Jenkins thus I can not use input step.

If there is a way to use the "trigger build remotely" plugin ac pipeline code but only for a single stage not for the completed job.